# How to put items according to a heading?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a 5000+ space separated lines as below:

```
Item_A: Acou#1  Bla#5

Item_B: Acou#1  Elfa#2  Flq#2

Item_C: Acou#1  Bla#4   Elfa#2  Flq#2

Item_D: Agly#3  Bla#4   Elfa#2
```

I want to make a table with common headers for all and quantity each in a table as below,

```
             Acou  Agly  Bla  Elfa  Flq

Item_A:      1     0     5    0     0

Item_B:      1     0     0    2     2

Item_C:      1     0     4    2     2

Item_D:      0     3     4    2     0
```

I used to grep lines containing "Acou", then, "Bla" and so on. Then edit in excel to quantify them and concatenate all separate files to one file. However, it took a lot of time.

Comment: Please detail what you have done until now and where exactly you need help. We are not a script "for hire" service, we are a Unix forum.

Comment: I used to grep lines containing "Acou", then, "Bla" and so on. Then edit in excel to quantify them and concatenate all separate files to one file. However, it took a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind throwing [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/download/) into the mix, then you could simply serialize the entries and then crosstabulate them:

```
awk '
  {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {split($i,a,"#"); print $1,a[1],a[2]}}' OFS='\t' file | 
  datamash --filler=0 crosstab 1,2 count 3
    Acou    Agly    Bla Elfa    Flq
Item_A: 1   0   1   0   0
Item_B: 1   0   0   1   1
Item_C: 1   0   1   1   1
Item_D: 0   1   1   1   0
```

Alternatively, with GNU awk (which allows multidimensional arrays):

```
gawk '
  BEGIN {
    OFS="\t";
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc";
  }
  {
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
      split($i,a,"#"); 
      h[a[1]] = 1;
      t[$1][a[1]] += a[2];
    }
  } 
  END {
    for (j in h) printf("\t%s", j);
    printf "\n";
    for (i in t) {
      printf("%s",i);
      for (j in h) 
        printf("\t%d", j in t[i] ? t[i][j] : 0);
      printf "\n";
    }
  }' file
    Acou    Agly    Bla Elfa    Flq
Item_A: 1   0   5   0   0
Item_B: 1   0   0   2   2
Item_C: 1   0   4   2   2
Item_D: 0   3   4   2   0
```

Comment: Add # to FS and you don't need to split: `FS = "[ \t#]+"` -- then `for (i=2; i<NF; i+=2) {h[$i]=1; t[$1][$i] = $(i+1)}`

Comment: Thank you @steeldriver. It works great and don't need to sort columns alphabetically as well. Much appreciated.

Comment: @steeldriver: The alternate version works; however, there is an error from datamash as:datamash: invalid operation 'crosstab'

Answer (score 3):

```
BEGIN { OFS = "\t" }

# Collect headers from data
FNR == NR {
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i)
        if (!($i in heads))
            heads[$i]
    next
}

# Output header
FNR == 1 {
    line = "Items"
    for (j in heads)
        line = line OFS j
    print line
}

{
    line = $1
    # Iterate through the header items, testing each field against it
    for (j in heads) {
        found = 0 # assume not found
        for (i = 2; !found && i <= NF; ++i)
            if ($i == j)
                found = 1 # matches header
        line = line OFS found
    }
    print line
}
```

Running this on your data (after having removed empty lines):

```
$ awk -f script.awk file file
Items   Acou#1  Bla#4   Bla#5   Elfa#2  Agly#3  Flq#2
Item_A: 1       0       1       0       0       0
Item_B: 1       0       0       1       0       1
Item_C: 1       1       0       1       0       1
Item_D: 0       1       0       1       1       0
```

Note that you have to specify the input data file twice.  This is because we're scanning it two times.  In the first scan we're collecting the data items on each line (the `FNR == NR` block).  On the second scan, we test each collected data item (the headers) against the data on each line.

The output is simply `0` if the field in the header is not present in the data on that line, and `1` if it is.  This is not *quite* what you asked for, so...

A variation that truncates the headers at the `#` and uses the part after the `#` as the data to display:

```
BEGIN { OFS = "\t" }

# Collect headers from data
FNR == NR {
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) {
        split($i, h, "#")
        if (!(h[1] in heads))
            heads[h[1]]
    }
    next
}

# Output header
FNR == 1 {
    line = "Items"
    for (j in heads)
        line = line OFS j
    print line
}

{
    line = $1
    # Iterate through the header items, testing each field against it
    for (j in heads) {
        found = 0 # assume not found
        for (i = 2; !found && i <= NF; ++i) {
            split($i, h, "#")
            if (h[1] == j)
                found = h[2] # matches header
        }
        line = line OFS found
    }
    print line
}
```

Running it:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file file
Items   Elfa    Bla     Acou    Agly    Flq
Item_A: 0       5       1       0       0
Item_B: 2       0       1       0       2
Item_C: 2       4       1       0       2
Item_D: 2       4       0       3       0
```

Note that the order of the columns is not necessarily sorted (since they are stored as keys in an associative array).  I'm leaving it as an exercise to the reader to sort them.

Comment: Thank you for detail explanation @Kusalananda. Much appreciated and works great as you have explained.